# How to paste data to the last empty row in another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row, paste

I know there are countless variations of this question on the internet. But I will say that no answer has helped me. I am trying to copy this database from one workbook to a different one.

And I want to paste this data immediately after the last filled row. Follow the images for better visualization of my problem:

Esta é a minha tabela no workbook 1. [workbook 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuV9W.png)

This is my table in workbook 2, where I filled some cells randomly as examples, to perform the copy and paste tests. [workbook 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnTs9.png)

Again, my intention is to pass the data from workbook 1 to workbook 2 and paste it immediately after the last row with content.

I had already tried that. But it gives the error "1004: Application definition or object definition error". I am new to vba. so not exactly where I am going wrong.

Also notice that in my code, I am rearranging the columns in the new workbook, is there anything I can do to make this more organized?

```
Sub copying()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\est_acpinheiro\Desktop\pypdf\table.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\est_acpinheiro\Desktop\pypdf\exporting.xlsx"

Workbooks("table.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Copy _
Workbooks("exporting.xlsx").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("E:E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'A-E

Workbooks("table.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Copy _
Workbooks("exporting.xlsx").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("G:G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  'B-G

Workbooks("table.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").Copy _
Workbooks("exporting.xlsx").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("A:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  'C-A
   
Workbooks("table.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D").Copy _
Workbooks("exporting.xlsx").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("C:C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  'D-C
 
Workbooks("table.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:E").Copy _
Workbooks("exporting.xlsx").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("B:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  'E-B

Workbooks("table.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F").Copy _
Workbooks("exporting.xlsx").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("I:I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  'F-I

Workbooks("table.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").Copy _
Workbooks("exporting.xlsx").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("K:K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  'G-K

Workbooks("table.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I:I").Copy _
Workbooks("exporting.xlsx").Worksheets("Plan1").Range("H:H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  'I-H

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't copy a whole column and paste it below the first row - there's no room for it to fit....   Also you need to find one value for "next empty row" or your data may not be lined up correctly in the destination worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most organized/clean that I'm currently able to offer you, however there are a few assumptions:

- You don't have a header in Sheet1, otherwise you need to start from A2, not A1
- You want to keep the formatting/etc. from Sheet1, otherwise you don't need `.Copy` but want to just set the values (is also faster but leading zeros on numbers (as text) would go lost)
- Your A-column has normally always a value so we can base the last row on that

---

```
Sub copying()
    
    Dim wbS As Workbook, wbD As Workbook, wsS As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
    Dim lRowS As Long, lRowD As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wbS = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\est_acpinheiro\Desktop\pypdf\table.xlsx")
    Set wsS = wbS.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lRowS = wsS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'assuming your A-column is usually always filled
    Set wbD = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\est_acpinheiro\Desktop\pypdf\exporting.xlsx")
    Set wsD = wbD.Worksheets("Plan1")
    lRowD = wsD.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    Dim arrS: arrS = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "I")
    Dim arrD: arrD = Array("E", "G", "A", "C", "B", "I", "K", "H")
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrS, 1)
        wsS.Range(arrS(i) & "1:" & arrS(i) & lRowS).Copy wsD.Range(arrD(i) & lRowD) 'I guess you don't have headings?
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much, I was more than a week trying to solve this problem and did not know how. I am very grateful for your help :)))))

Comment: You're welcome, hope everything is clear :)